# Latency spikes when Ping or SSH to Macbook Pro 15(2017) macOS Catalina 15.4

Tags: network, wifi, ssh, dns

I have noticed that when trying to connect to macOS Catalina through ssh over local wireless network, the connection will encounter a serious latency problem, which makes me hard to type into anything through ssh. (The latency tested using Ping ranges from 3500ms to 2ms)
I have checked all forums mentioned this issue, some of those proposed solutions like disabling DNS or GSAPI, but those doesn't work for me. 
I have checked packets by Wireshark and surprisingly found that all packet of ssh are still transferring by IPV6 even I have disabled it in both the router and the sshd_config.
Wish there could be some suggestions that can help me solve the problem.

Comment: How far apart are your MacBook Pro and the wireless Access Point? - Have you tried setting the AP to a different channel?

Comment: Range within a meter. I didn’t encounter any lag when connected to Linux server under the same circumstance.

Comment: Have you tried using a cabled connection to see if that works properly?

Comment: Oh, I didn't. As I don't have a dongle with the ethernet port. May you suggest it's only related with the wireless card?

Comment: Well, yes that's the assumption that can either be validated or disproven by checking with a cable.